# looping setRows in Google-apps-script for Google forms

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

In the context of Google forms, using Google apps script, I am trying to create a form of grid-multiple choice type. 
I am using following code to loop the rows - the aim is to have roll number of students on the rows and their grades in columns:
Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var form = FormApp.create('Peer_Grading_');
  var name = form.addTextItem();
  name.setTitle('Your Name');
  var rnum=form.addTextItem();
  rnum.setTitle('Your Roll Number');
  var item = form.addGridItem()

  item.setTitle('Grade Matrix')
  for(var i=1; i<=30; i=i+1){

    if(i<10){
      item.setRows(['16633000'+i])

    }
    else{
      item.setRows(['1663300'+i])

    }
  };
  item.setColumns(['AA', 'AB', 'BB', 'BC', 'CC', 'CD']);
}
```

But I am getting this screenshot as output: [screenshot of the form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdC30.png)

Only the last roll number is coming as an output of for loop.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are overwriting the row in the loop.  Try using an array then push the data in the loop:

```
function myFunctionForm() {
  var form = FormApp.create('Peer_Grading_');
  var name = form.addTextItem();
  name.setTitle('Your Name');
  var rnum=form.addTextItem();
  rnum.setTitle('Your Roll Number');
  var item = form.addGridItem()

  var rowArr = []

  item.setTitle('Grade Matrix')
  for(var i=1; i<=30; i=i+1){

    if(i<10){
  rowArr.push('16633000'+i)

    }
    else{
    rowArr.push(['1663300'+i])

    }
  };
   item.setColumns(['AA', 'AB', 'BB', 'BC', 'CC', 'CD']);
  item.setRows(rowArr);

}
```

Comment: this helped.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted